# Waypoint Circuit has issues in Game mode but fixes itself in Scene view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am attaching waypoint circuits to gameobjects as they spawn dynamically. When I run the scene, the waypoint system doesn't seem to attach properly and I'm given the NullReferenceException below. In the same run, if I switch to the Scene view, the issue disappears, the error is no longer thrown and gameobjects magically begin to follow the waypoint circuit as expected. The problem also occurs when I run it as a standalone build.

I've searched around for a similar issue. It seems like a bug, what could be wrong on my side that would make something go wrong in Game mode but work as soon as I open the Scene view?

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityStandardAssets.Utility.WaypointCircuit.GetRoutePosition (Single dist) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Utility/WaypointCircuit.cs:66)
UnityStandardAssets.Utility.WaypointCircuit.GetRoutePoint (Single dist) (at Assets/Standard Assets/Utility/WaypointCircuit.cs:53)
UnityStandardAssets.Utility.WaypointProgressTracker.Update () (at Assets/Standard Assets/Utility/WaypointProgressTracker.cs:108)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with execution order and filling the circuit with waypoints before Unity's WaypointCircuit script initialized. The script was initializing before my gameobject-spawning script would and would find an empty circuit. Switching to the Scene view would make the WaypointCircuit script check for waypoints again and since some time passed, it would find a non-empty circuit and the objects would follow the circuit as expected.

Making sure that the circuit is filled with waypoints before the WaypointCircuit script initializes did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if using WaypointCircuit component when I am in Console window, this error will appear. I turn to Scene window, instead of Console, and click "Add child" button again, it work with me